# Should I update information after Kenyan visa was granted?

Tags: visas, us-citizens, applications, kenya

I'm an American. A month or so ago, I applied for and got a Kenyan visa for a volunteer trip I'm taking this summer. On the application, it asked "What countries have you visited in the past three months?" to which I put none.

At the time, this was true. But today, my friend and I booked a last minute trip to Mexico City (because flights were dirt cheap). But doing this makes my visa application information outdated..

I obviously don't want to, but I have 24 hours to cancel my flight. In that time, the Kenyan embassies in the US will not be open, nor will the customer service line listed on the Kenyan visa website.

Comment: The information on your application was accurate at the time you submitted it though, right?

Comment: There has been no material change in your eligibility after acquiring the visa. Mexico is not for example Syria where some countries would flag you for extra scrutiny related to terrorism. Relax.

Comment: Those visa questions are meant to cover everything up to and including the application stage.

Comment: Kenya certainly won't care and I wouldn't even mention it to the Border Guard unless asked directly about it.

Answer (score 1):

No, you do not need to update anything as the information you've submitted at the time of the application was valid. You cannot be expected to continuously inform them about every little new detail up until your visa is issued.

Relax and enjoy your stay in Mexico.

Answer (score -1):

No, not unless there has been a significant change, which, under either Kenyan law or in the estimation of Kenyan officials, would bar your entry. That is very unlikely to apply to an American who travels briefly to a nearby country. It might, for example, if you had gone to an area where yellow fever is a risk and your passport shows that you visited such a country. In that case, the government of Kenya would need evidence of vaccination before allowing you entry. Mexico is not on [the list](https://wwwnc.cdc.gov/travel/yellowbook/2018/infectious-diseases-related-to-travel/yellow-fever#5291).

Comment: The yellow fever vaccination is not a visa requirement.  Where there is such a requirement, it is generally enforced at the time of entry (or, for air travelers, by the airline at the time of boarding).

Comment: @Dorothy might be worth updating your answer?